# Push logs to a port from kafka connector

Tags: java, apache-kafka-connect

From custom kafka connect sink connector is there a way to push all the logs to a port or we need to write a custom log appender to handle the same ?

I will like to split the task in 2 steps (in case it cannot be achieved directly):

1) Write all the kafka connect distributed logs to a log file on the local directory
2) Publish logs on a port from the log file

So, is there a way to write all the kafka connect logs (start up and connection establishment messages) as well as the logs of the application/business logic ?

Comment: Can you explain why you're wanting to do this? From the sounds of it you want to take the logs from your Connect tasks and put them somewhere else, is that right? What's the "somewhere else"? This sounds like something you'd want to do in Connect itself, rather than the custom connector

Comment: I want to post kafka  connector application logs to a port exposed by logstash. So, that I can host all my kafka connect logs in elastic search

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Connect uses [Log4J](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/), so any interface with the logging that you want would be through that. It looks like you've [previously realised that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332265/log4j-logging-on-remote-host-and-port) :)

Using the [`SocketAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketAppender.html) is simple enough to do with Kafka Connect.

Here's an example configuration that works when I add it to my `etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, server
log4j.appender.server=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.server.Port=4512
log4j.appender.server.RemoteHost=localhost
log4j.appender.server.ReconnectionDelay=10000
```

Then when I start up connect:

```
$ ./bin/connect-distributed ./etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties
```

and using netcat in a separate session I see this:

```
$ nc -l -k 4512
��sr!org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent��#t�?
ZmdcCopyLookupRequiredZndcLookupRequiredJ       timeStampLcategoryNametLjava/lang/String;LlocationInfot#Lorg/apache/log4j/spi/LocationInfo;LmdcCopytLjava/util/Hashtable;Lndcq~LrenderedMessageq~L
throwableInfot+Lorg/apache/log4j/spi/ThrowableInformation;xp^�'�t@org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoaderpppt<Registered loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6tmainpwN pxysr!org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent��#t�?
ZmdcCopyLookupRequiredZndcLookupRequiredJ       timeStampLcategoryNametLjava/lang/String;LlocationInfot#Lorg/apache/log4j/spi/LocationInfo;LmdcCopytLjava/util/Hashtable;Lndcq~LrenderedMessageq~L
throwableInfot+Lorg/apache/log4j/spi/ThrowableInformation;xp^�'�'t@org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoaderppptDAdded plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector'tmainpwN pxysr!org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent��#t�?
ZmdcCopyLookupRequiredZndcLookupRequiredJ       timeStampLcategoryNametLjava/lang/String;LlocationInfot#Lorg/apache/log4j/spi/LocationInfo;LmdcCopytLjava/util/Hashtable;Lndcq~LrenderedMessageq~L
```

You'd then need to run the [log4j logstash plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-log4j.html) to decode this.

---

You may want to read this note about [sending Log4J to Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/blog/log4j-input-logstash); there the answer is instead to use Filebeat.

Comment: Thanks for the response !! Based on above link, below is a note - 
`Our recommendation is for current Log4j input users to stop using log4j’s SocketAppender in their applications. For safe transport of log4j logs, users should configure log4j to write logs to disk and use Filebeat to forward to log information to Logstash`
This can be a challenge to write logs to a file and then transfer to the logstash in case of docker containers.